# How to read "msDS-ResultantPSO" attribute value of AD user using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to access "msDS-ResultantPSO" attribute value of AD user using C#,I applied the Password Policy on a user, and its showing the value in "msDS-ResultantPSO" attribute.Now, I am trying to get this value using C# in the same way to get Normal attributes of AD user such as "FirstName, LastName,Email...".I added ResulantPSO attribute along with other normal attributes to load.My code bringing all normal attributes values except "msDS-ResultantPSO".

Please can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make sure the user running my program had the appropriate AD read permissions other than that this should get you close:

```
var ad = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domain, _ldapPathOu);

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ad, username);
DirectoryEntry entry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
SearchResultCollection results;
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-ResultantPSO");

results = mySearcher.FindAll();

if (results.Count >= 1)
{
    string pso = results[0].Properties["msDS-ResultantPSO"][0].ToString();

    //do something with the pso..
    DirectoryEntry d = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://corp.example.com/"+ pso);

    var searchForPassPolicy = new DirectorySearcher(d);
    searchForPassPolicy.Filter = @"(objectClass=msDS-PasswordSettings)";
    searchForPassPolicy.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;

    searchForPassPolicy.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] {"msDS-MaximumPasswordAge"});
    var x = searchForPassPolicy.FindAll();

    var maxAge = (Int64)x[0].Properties["msDS-MaximumPasswordAge"][0];
    var maxPwdAgeInDays = ConvertTimeToDays(maxAge);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to provide this answer, it is very similar to what I am looking for. My issue is that msDS-ResultantPSO is a constructed attribute and i am unable to retrieve it through directorysearcher as in your example. Any advice?

Comment: Got it working, problem was on my end and your example was perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @MattSanders No problem! Just saw this, glad you were able to make it work!